# pointer arithmetic in multi-dimensional array

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

I know that for two-dimensional arrays  `A[i][j]`is equivalent to `*(*(A+i)+j)`, but what does `(int *Arrptr)[5] mean?`

Comment: Did you change your question?

Comment: @PeterG. `(int *Arrptr)[5]` is wrong syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(int *Arrptr)[5]` is wrong syntax.

```
int (*Arrptr)[5]; // Arrptr is a pointer to an array of 5 int
int *Arrptr[5];  // Arrptr is an array of 5 pointeres to int
```

The array subscript operator `[]` binds tightly to the identifier `Arrptr`, therefore parentheses are necessary in the first statement.